# Wget doen't work in /etc/cron.d/ using symlink? (I have a Raspberry Pi)

Tags: ftp, raspberry-pi, symbolic-link, wget, cron

I have a cronfile in `/home/pi/path/` and made a symlink into `/etc/cron.d/cron_some_file`. I want to update the cron file automatically (I want to make changes from the server so I won't have to access the Raspberry Pi directly) using wget with the following line:

```
1 */3 * * * root wget -m -nH --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=pass ftp://ip_addres_of_the_server/path
```

If I write it manually it downloads if something was changed in some files, but in the cronfile it doesn't work. I looked in the syslog file and I get the following errors:

```
**cron[451]:Error: bad username; while reading /etc/cron.d/cron_some_file**

**cron[451]:(*system*cron_some_file) ERROR(Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)**
```

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: "bad username;"

I think you're editing Cron the wrong way. Try 'sudo crontab -e' and paste that line without 'root'.

Comment: I am editing it in the terminal with nano

Comment: Sure, but call it via 'sudo crontab -e'

Comment: I have the files on the server and i want to edit them from there, and i want cron to download them automatically every 3 hours, because i will not have direct acess to thyem in the near future

Comment: Yes, but... you are doing 'crontab -e' or 'sudo crontab -e'? You can't run commands as root from a normal user cron.

Comment: But i have my file in /etc/cron.d

Comment: It worked before and i don't get it why it doesn't anymore, from where i edit the file the operating system is wondows 7 pro

Comment: isn't the /etc/cron.d the system wide crontab file ? so normal users can't access it, i edit with sudo nano and the /home/user/cron_some_file. This cron_some_file is linked to /etc/cron.d/